# $x^2+y^2$, $x^2-y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve this problem: "Given that $x^2 + y^2 = 3$ and $x^2 - y^2 = 4$, find the value of $x^4 - y^4$."

The book says the answer is 12, but I don't understand how to set up the problem to arrive at that answer. (I am doing an algebra review, so I don't know where in the book to look for explanation.)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implication is that you should use the difference of squares identity, but it has been disguised here:
$$x^4-y^4=(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)$$

Comment: Thanks! Now I know what to review next.